# MBCS Not present in VS2015 after installing MFC and VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, mbcs

I've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and trying to get some 2013 projects to build. According to MSDN documentation, the MBCS library is built into VS2015 as long as MFC and VC++ are installed. My projects' Platform Toolset is set to v120 (Visual Studio 2013) as it has not been uplifted to v140.

I'm receiving MSB8031 - error MSB8031: Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820 for more information.

I've tried reinstalling VS2015 a couple times, even including every single option in the install screen with no luck. The 2013 MBCS library installer does not run since I do not have VS2013 installed. Is there something I'm missing for VS2015 to build 2013 projects relying on the MBCS library?

Comment: Hmm, no, you cannot use the v120 toolset if you don't have VS2013 installed.  How you made this happen anyway is something you cannot leave out of the question.  Don't hack this by copying files, you'll be bogged down chasing problems like this forever.  Targeting v140 is the obvious way to get ahead.

Comment: VS2015 allows you to target the v120 toolset when attempting to open projects meant for it; no hacking was done. I agree on targeting v140, however this is unfortunately out of our control due to the size of our codebase. Thanks for the clarification, I had a bad feeling this wouldn't work.